# How to search for two inverted commas, python?

Tags: python-3.x

Hi guys in my assignment I need my code to return a print message to say that on one particular line there is only one inverted comma, any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you post here the code that you already have, your input, your output, and the output you would like to get instead, you are much more likely to receive an answer quickly. Please also read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: if ('if ') in line:
        print ('exists')
    elif (' " " ') in line:
        print ('inverted commas exist')
    else:
        print('does not exist')
        print('inverted commas do not exist')

thats the code I have, I want the output to tell me whether the line being checked has two inverted commas or not and I have no idea how to do that, if I put two quotes in the elif it says two inverted commas don't exist on the line where there are two inverted commas in the text being read.

Comment: Could you put your code into the question itself and also give an example string that you want to check (in the question)?